# Add Bootsrap or Materialize to angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to add `bootstrap` or `materializ` to my project. I just follow instructions from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter#external-stylesheets because I download this starter but its not working when I do things like they showed. I get such error

> external "vendor_lib":1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: 
>   @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
>   ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss.

I have it in my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/common": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/core": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/forms": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/http": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.3",
"@angular/router": "~4.0.3",
"@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.13",
"@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
"materialize-css": "^0.98.2",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
"rxjs": "5.0.2",
"zone.js": "~0.8.5"
},
```